# Change placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the placeholder text of an input element?

For example I have 3 inputs of type text.

```
<input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Some Text">
<input type="text" name="First Name" placeholder="Some Text">
<input type="text" name="Last Name"placeholder="Some Text">
```

How can I change the **Some Text** text using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Did you try `$('input').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');`?

Comment: Have you tried anything with javascript or jquery ? Please post what you have tried and what are the issues you faced.

Comment: You can use malarkey

Answer (score 199, accepted):

If you wanna use Javascript then you can use `getElementsByName()` method to select the `input` fields and to change the `placeholder` for each one... see the below code...

```
document.getElementsByName('Email')[0].placeholder='new text for email';
document.getElementsByName('First Name')[0].placeholder='new text for fname';
document.getElementsByName('Last Name')[0].placeholder='new text for lname';
```

Otherwise use jQuery:

```
$('input:text').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');
```

Comment: +1 for going native without using external libraries ... people need to pay attention to the DOM APIs you might not need to use a whole library just to do something simple like that.

Comment: Often the field already contains a value, so the placeholder will not be visible. You must clear the value.

    `var email = document.getElementsByName("Email")[0];`
    `email.value='';`
    `email.placeholder='new text for email';`

Answer (score 30):

This solution uses jQuery. If you want to use same placeholder text for all text inputs, you can use

```
$('input:text').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');
```

And if you want different placeholders, you can use the element's id to change placeholder

```
$('#element1_id').attr('placeholder','Some New Text 1');
$('#element2_id').attr('placeholder','Some New Text 2');
```

Answer (score 18):

```
var input = document.getElementById ("IdofInput");
input.placeholder = "No need to fill this field";
```

You can find out more about `placeholder` here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljgugboo.php

Answer (score 6):

Using jquery you can do this by following code:

```
<input type="text" id="tbxEmail" name="Email" placeholder="Some Text"/>

$('#tbxEmail').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been facing the same problem.

In JS, first you have to clear the textbox of the text input. Otherwise the placeholder text won't show.

Here's my solution.

```
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value="";
document.getElementsByName("email")[0].placeholder="your message";
```

Comment: That's right. Without setting the field to blank first, the placeholder doesn't  show up. Spent a long long time on this until I bumped on this post.

Answer (score 2):

Try accessing the placeholder attribute of the input and change its value like the following:

```
$('#some_input_id').attr('placeholder','New Text Here');
```

Can also clear the placeholder if required like:

```
$('#some_input_id').attr('placeholder','');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your javascript file

document.getElementsByName('Email')[0].placeholder = 'new text for email';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select-holder')[0].placeholder = "This is my new text";
```

For jQuery use:

```
$('.select-holder')[0].placeholder = "This is my new text";
```