# change labels value with javascript, when no id or class

Tags: javascript, selector

Can you help me for changing value with javascript, but code no have id or class here is code:

```
<label for="flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en">Origin</label>
```

I want change "Origin" with different word.

Some examples of my code:

```
<button role="flights_submit" type="submit">Search</button>
<div class="mewtwo-flights-destination">
<label for="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en">Destination</label>
<input type="text" 
       name="destination_name" 
       autocomplete="off" required="" 
       id="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en" 
       placeholder="Destination" 
       data-label="Destination" 
       role="flights-destination" 
       data-modal-modifier="whitelabel_en" 
       data-placeholder-initialized="true">

<input type="hidden" 
       name="destination_iata" 
       id="flights-destination-whitelabel_en" value="">
</div>
```

How can change this placeholder "Destination", and label text Destination?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the origin texto doing this:

```
document.querySelector("label[for='flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en']").textContent = 'New Text';
```

Comment: It would be slightly faster to drop the label selector portion also. So: document.querySelector("[for='flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en']")

Comment: And, don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't passing any HTML, use `textContent` instead.

Comment: Sorry its not working for me here is Link: http://booking.aviabiletebi.org/

Comment: on jsfiddle its working but on my site not https://jsfiddle.net/ds1r7sLs/

Comment: Works on your site for me. Just open the javascript console and type document.querySelector("[for='flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en']");
it will return the label.

Comment: Yes, its returning null also for me but when i add code in source nothing heppend

Comment: this code in console works 100% document.querySelector("label[for='flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en']").textContent = 'New Text';

in my source 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
document.querySelector("label[for='flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en']").textContent = 'New Text';
  });
 </script>

not working thanks :(

Comment: Its tag maybe loading after js code compile. how can we add timer for run

Comment: The `.textContent` method is not cross browser compliant.  Use the ternary method to determine whether the browser accepts `innerText` or `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure, you can use `querySelector` with label selector including for data

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("label[for='flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en']"))
```

```html
<button role="flights_submit" type="submit">Search</button>
<div class="mewtwo-flights-destination">
<label for="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en">Destination</label>
<input type="text" 
       name="destination_name" 
       autocomplete="off" required="" 
       id="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en" 
       placeholder="Destination" 
       data-label="Destination" 
       role="flights-destination" 
       data-modal-modifier="whitelabel_en" 
       data-placeholder-initialized="true">

<input type="hidden" 
       name="destination_iata" 
       id="flights-destination-whitelabel_en" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: It would be slightly faster to drop the label selector portion also. So: document.querySelector("[for='flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en']")

Comment: its catching, but dont working for my website here is link: booking.aviabiletebi.org

Comment: I copied this to console and it works `document.querySelector('label[for="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en"]')` (on your webpage)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct element using an "attribute selector" that looks for the `for` attribute and a specific value for it.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var el = document.querySelector("[for=flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en]");
  el.textContent = "New Value";
  
  var input = document.getElementById("flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en");
  input.setAttribute("placeholder","New Value");

  
});
```

```html
<button role="flights_submit" type="button">Search</button>
<div class="mewtwo-flights-destination">
<label for="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en">Destination</label>
<input type="text" 
       name="destination_name" 
       autocomplete="off" required="" 
       id="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en" 
       placeholder="Destination" 
       data-label="Destination" 
       role="flights-destination" 
       data-modal-modifier="whitelabel_en" 
       data-placeholder-initialized="true">

<input type="hidden" 
       name="destination_iata" 
       id="flights-destination-whitelabel_en" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to set an array of the elements you want to target, which in this case is `label`.  Then you would iterate through that array using a `for` loop  to see if the `textContent` of that `label` is what you wanted to change.  Finally, once you've 'hooked' the label you need, you can change the attributes for it as necessary.  Please also note that `textContent` method is not cross browser compliant and so I've included a ternary script that will circumvent that thanks to [this handy StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11646618/5076162) .

> HTML:

```
<button role="flights_submit" type="submit">Search</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="mewtwo-flights-destination">
    <label for="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en">Destination</label>

    <input type="text" name="destination_name" autocomplete="off" required="" id="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en" placeholder="Destination" data-label="Destination" role="flights-destination" data-modal-modifier="whitelabel_en" data-placeholder-initialized="true">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="somethingElse">OtherLabel</label>
    <input type="text" id='somethingElse'>

    <input type="hidden" name="destination_iata" id="somethingElse" value="">
</div>
```

> JavaScript:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/285608/5076162
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506703/5076162

var labelArray = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
console.log(labelArray);
var textToChange = 'Destination';

for (var i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++) {
    var currentLabel = labelArray[i]
    var text = ('innerText' in labelArray[i]) ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
    if (currentLabel[text] === 'Destination') {
        var matchingInput = document.getElementById(currentLabel.htmlFor);
        var newText = 'changedDestination';
        var newPlaceHolder = 'changedPlaceHolder';

        currentLabel[text] = newText;
        matchingInput.placeholder = newPlaceHolder;
    }
}
```

> [jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/5hb8u4yL/)

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/285608/5076162
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506703/5076162

var labelArray = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
console.log(labelArray);
var textToChange = 'Destination';

for (var i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++) {
  var currentLabel = labelArray[i]
  var text = ('innerText' in labelArray[i]) ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
  if (currentLabel[text] === 'Destination') {
    var matchingInput = document.getElementById(currentLabel.htmlFor);
    var newText = 'changedDestination';
    var newPlaceHolder = 'changedPlaceHolder';

    currentLabel[text] = newText;
    matchingInput.placeholder = newPlaceHolder;
  }
}
```

```html
<button role="flights_submit" type="submit">Search</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="mewtwo-flights-destination">
  <label for="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en">Destination</label>

  <input type="text" name="destination_name" autocomplete="off" required="" id="flights-destination-prepop-whitelabel_en" placeholder="Destination" data-label="Destination" role="flights-destination" data-modal-modifier="whitelabel_en" data-placeholder-initialized="true">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="somethingElse">OtherLabel</label>
  <input type="text" id='somethingElse'>

  <input type="hidden" name="destination_iata" id="somethingElse" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if wanna get the label for with contains text for me is using this one

```
document.querySelector("label[for*='flights-origin-prepop-whitelabel_en']").textContent = 'New Text';
```