# Add Placeholder text to a text field in a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi all i am trying to add placeholder to a skin i am building on roundcube.
i want it to say username for username and password for password.
i know its possible using html but the issue is i dont have acess to the form so i can add placeholder text to the html.
I think the only way will be with js or css but as of yet not found a working solution and hoping someone here can help.
Here is the form html it has:

```
    <html>
<input type="hidden" name="_task" value="login"><input type="hidden" name="_action" value="login"><input type="hidden" name="_timezone" id="rcmlogintz" value="_default_"><input type="hidden" name="_url" id="rcmloginurl" value=""><table><tbody><tr><td class="title"><label for="rcmloginuser">Username</label>
</td>
    <td class="input"><input name="_user" id="rcmloginuser" required="required" size="40" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class="title"><label for="rcmloginpwd">Password</label>
    </td>
    <td class="input"><input name="_pass" id="rcmloginpwd" required="required" size="40" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="password"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </html>
```

Many thanks all.

Comment: Is that the correct HTML, it's all over the place, it has TD's without TR, it has TR without THEAD/TBODY, and then no TABLE.. mmm..

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: @Keith — The thead element is optional. The tbody start tag is optional. It's a form, tables shouldn't be used for layout anyway.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506481/change-placeholder-text

Comment: hi yes its the output from the bit i think you guys need

Comment: @Quentin   That's not really my point.. :)

Comment: @D.Braun i did try that before i asked, couldent get it to work, not a js coder so no idea why.

Comment: Have you tried getElementsByName or getElementById or the JQuery way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute `placeholder` and along with `setAttribute` function, set the desired placeholder.

```js
document.getElementsByName('_user')[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Username");
document.getElementsByName('_pass')[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Password");
```

```html
<html>
<td class="input">
<br><label for="rcmloginuser">Username</label><br>
<input name="_user" id="rcmloginuser" required="required" size="40" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="title"><br><label for="rcmloginpwd">Password</label><br>
</td>
<td class="input"><input name="_pass" id="rcmloginpwd" required="required" size="40" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="password"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</html>
```

See? now your fields have a placeholder.

## Resources

- [placeholder Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)
- [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you can select your HTML  element and define its placeholder :

```
document.getElementById("yourId").placeholder = "Placeholder";
```

Answer (score 0):

A Pure JS Solution would be as below :-

`document.getElementById("rcmloginuser").setAttribute("placeholder", "UserName");`

You can refer to the following JS Fiddle :-

https://jsfiddle.net/23nigam/q2493u3s/4/